# When compiling code I get the bad operand error

Tags: java, arrays, compiler-errors, boolean

Every time I try to compile my code I get a 'bad operand' error involving boolean and int arrays. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

```
System.out.println("Passed: " + passed); 

if (exam.totalIncorrect() > 0)
{
    System.out.println("The incorrect answers are: "); 

    int missedIndex; 

    for (int i = 0; i < exam.totalIncorrect(); i++)
    {
        missedIndex = exam.questionsMissed()[i]+1; 
        System.out.print(" " + missedIndex); 
    }
}
```

The error I get is this:

```
   DriverExamApplication.java:58: error: bad operand types for binary operator   
   '+'   
            missedIndex = exam.questionsMissed() [i] +1; 

                                         ^

first type:  boolean

second type: int
```

Comment: Issue is with trying to add a boolean to integer. Could you try to tell me the thinking behind the line `missedIndex = exam.questionsMissed()[i]+1; `?

Comment: Every time you *try to compile* your code you get this *compilation error*. You can't run it before you compile it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to add a boolean with an integer....

Print it directly and save time converting types

```
System.out.print(" " + exam.questionsMissed()[i]+i+1);
```

Comment: sorry I am newer to programming. So, [i] + 1 is not valid. Would I just delete the addition for it to work?

Comment: Thank you for the response. Sorry for the newb question. I am definitely a beginner trying to teach myself programming. The change worked great.

Comment: When I ran my code everything ran fine, but the output appeared as "false1 false1 false1" from the code piece you gave me. It's supposed to display the incorrect question numbers in the array list.

Comment: Yes... Print i+1 instead of 1...I just updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `exam.questionsMissed()` returns an array of boolean. Then `exam.questionsMissed()[i]` is boolean, and you are trying append 1 to it.